# Error al subir un archivo pdf

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de subir un archivo a una carpeta en donde se puede almacesar acrchivos .pdf, pero solo me sube el nombre del archivo a la base de datos, pero no logro que suba el archivo.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['texto']) && !empty($_POST['archivo'])) {
        $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO punioyletra (titulo, texto, archivo) VALUES (:titulo, :texto, :archivo)");
        $add->bindValue(':titulo', $_POST['titulo']);
        $add->bindValue(':texto', $_POST['texto']);
        $add->bindValue(':archivo', '../../pdf' . $_POST['archivo']);
        $add->execute();

        header('location: ../');
    } else {
        echo '<div class="cmpl">Hay campos vacios</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Este es el formulario

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo" autocomplete="off"><br>
<textarea name="texto" placeholder="Texto"></textarea><br>
<input type="file" name="archivo">
<br><br>
<button class="srbs-btn-primary btn" name="add">Publicar</button>
</form>
```

Como resultado me da que hay campos vacios. Si quito la opsion de subir archivos, todo funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta hacer referencia al fichero, no vale `$_POST['archivo']` porque los campos `file`  se gestionan un poco diferente.

Antes de la imputación en la base de datos tienes que verificar que en `$_FILES` te llega lo que esperas. Esta variable se trabaja igual que `$_POST`, es un array donde te llega la información del formulario, puedes ver su contenido con:

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_FILES);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Así te familiarizaras con su estructura.

Una vez que sabes que ha llegado al servidor el fichero, lo tienes que copiar  su ubicación definitiva y ya entonces guardas en base de datos lo que necesites (generalmente la ruta y nombre definitivo del fichero subido).

Este proceso de copiado se realiza mediante la función: `move_uploaded_file()`

Como ejemplo:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/ficheros_subidos';
foreach ($_FILES['archivo']['error'] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() puede evitar ataques de denegación de sistema de ficheros;
        // podría ser apropiada más validación/saneamiento del nombre del fichero
        $name = basename($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Tienes más información en la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Que tiene que ver esto con su problema que es que si pone fichero no le llega `$_POST['add']`???

Comment: Lo que no le llega es $_POST['archivo']

Comment: Edité la pregunta para poner una sangría correcta al código y que se vea más claro.

Comment: gracias, entiendo lo que medice e hice varias pruebas y por separado los archivos suben bien, pero no se porque no me guarda el archivo en el directorio **pdf**

Comment: Generalmente es un problema de permisos o de una ruta mal escrita, pero si no pones el código ni das más pistas poco podemos hacer. Fíjate que `move_uploaded_file()` devolverá `false` si no tiene éxito y no se si en el log de apache dejará algún rastro de dicho error.

Comment: tambien, hice algo como esto `$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$guardado = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

if(!file_exists('archivos')){
 mkdir('archivos',0777,true);
 if(file_exists('archivos')){
  if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
   echo "Archivo guardado con exito";
  }else{
   echo "Archivo no se pudo guardar";
  }
 }
}else{
 if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
  echo "Archivo guardado con exito";
 }else{
  echo "Archivo no se pudo guardar";
 }
}` pero no puedo adaptarlo

Comment: Edita la pregunta, aquí no se ve nada. ¿que quieres decir con "no puedo adaptarlo"  ?  explica bien cual es el error que te da ahora, cuanto mas preciso ms fácil ayudarte.